# How do I use clicks in duncan3dc / dusk?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I wrote, what code below is use in laravel's controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use duncan3dc\Laravel\Dusk;

$dusk = new Dusk;

    $dusk->visit("http://example.com")
        ->resize(1920,1080)
       ->screenshot('./ddd'.time().'.png');
```

this is work, 
but code below  is not working:

```
    $dusk = new Dusk;

    $dusk->visit("http://example.com")
        ->resize(1920,1080)
        ->click('body > div > p:nth-child(3) > a')
        ->screenshot('./ddd'.time().'.png');
```

i want use click and mouseover and keyboard managing in page.

i have read what changelog and https://laravel.kr/docs/5.6/dusk#clicking-links , all of document in https://packagist.org/packages/duncan3dc/dusk 
but it is hard of understand because my english is poor

i used all of function in laravel manual and document but failed

can you advice this problum and tell me what systematic document about duncan3dc / dusk for me ?
thanks for your read.

Comment: Is there an error? What's the message?

Comment: i got this err <no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body body > div > p:nth-child(3) > a"} (Session info: headless chrome=68.0.3440.84) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)> 
Please help me,,,,

Comment: `body` is automatically added to the selector. Try `->click('> div > p:nth-child(3) > a')`.

Comment: thank for you advice!! i'm solve my problum using your answr. thank so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` is automatically added to the selector. Use this:

```
->click('> div > p:nth-child(3) > a')
```